# ScalaMock for datastax-spark cassandra connector method "joinWithCassandra"

Tags: cassandra, spark-streaming, scalatest, datastax-java-driver, scalamock

I am trying to mock in Scala the joinWithCassandra method from datastax spark connector. I am getting error in compile. Please guide what am I doing wrong.

> Error:(59, 23) not enough arguments for constructor DStream: (ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[Any])org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[Any].
>   Unspecified value parameter ssc.
>       var mockObj = mock[DStream[Any]]

```
var mockObj = mock[DStream[Any]]

(mockObj.joinWithCassandraTable _).expects(sys.env.getOrElse(Config.KEY_SPACE_ENV, Config.DEFAULT_KEY_SPACE), sys.env.getOrElse(Config.DEVICE_CASSANDRA_TABLE_ENV, Config.DEFAULT_DEVICE_CASSANDRA_TABLE), SomeColumns("a", "b", "c"), SomeColumns("a")) returns(DStream[(AAAEvent, CassandraRow)])
```